# How to take input in LINQ from textbox C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a data table `dt_Customers` which contains some customers information. In this data table I want to select a range of ZIP codes which the user will enter using a text box.

I am using following code:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> enumerableDataRowCollection =
   from company in dt_Customers.AsEnumerable()
   let zip = company.Field<string>("ZIP")
   where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(zip) && (zip[0] >= "'" + txtBox_ZIP_From.Text + "'" && zip[0] <=  "'" + txtBox_ZIP_to.Text + "'"))

   select company;
```

But I am getting an error

```
Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'
```

The above code works fine when I hard code some value, like this:

```
zip[0] >= '2' && zip[0] <= '6'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> enumerableDataRowCollection =
   from company in dt_Customers.AsEnumerable()
   let zip = company.Field<string>("ZIP")
   where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(zip) && (zip >= txtBox_ZIP_From.Text && zip <=  txtBox_ZIP_to.Text))
```

if txtBox contient a singel char

```
var cCriterFrom = txtBox_ZIP_From.Text.Text[0];
var cCriterTo = txtBox_ZIP_to.Text.Text[0];

IEnumerable<DataRow> enumerableDataRowCollection =
   from company in dt_Customers.AsEnumerable()
   let zip = company.Field<string>("ZIP")
   where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(zip) && (zip[0] >= cCriterFrom && zip[0] <= cCriterTo))
```

Comment: `zip[0] >= cCriter && zip[0] <= cCriter` is equivalent to `zip[0] == cCriter`

Answer (score 1):

`Zip[0]` is a character, and `txtBox_ZIP_From.Text` is a String. In the given hard-coded example you're comparing a character and a character.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `zip` is a `string`, so `zip[n]` is a `char`. If you want to compare strings, try this:

```
string.Compare(zip, txtBox_ZIP_From.Text) >= 0 &&
string.Compare(zip, txtBox_ZIP_To.Text) <= 0
```

However, it might be better to convert `zip` and the text box inputs to numbers, and compare them that way.

Or if you just want to compare the first characters in each string, you can use this:

```
zip[0] >= txtBox_ZIP_From.Text[0] && zip[0] <=  txtBox_ZIP_to.Text[0]
```

Comment: I want to select the first digit from ZIP codes that why I used char datatype and the I am using ZIP[0].

Comment: @Kami Is there any reason why you're doing `"'" + txtBox_ZIP_From.Text + "'"`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> enumerableDataRowCollection =
   from company in dt_Customers.AsEnumerable()
   let zip = company.Field<string>("ZIP")
   where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(zip) && (zip.CompareTo(txtBox_ZIP_From.Text) >= 0) && (zip.CompareTo(txtBox_ZIP_to.Text) <=0))    
   select company;
```